# How to count occurrences for each unique element by column?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d array and want to get the occurrences of all unique numbers by column.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,2,3,3],
              [2,3,3,3],
              [3,3,4,4]])
```

The result should be

```
[[2,1,0,0],
 [1,2,2,2],
 [0,0,1,1]])
```

For example, the first row is the occurrence of number `2` in each column, 0 means `2` isn't in the third and fourth columns. The second row is the occurrence of the number `3` while the last row is for the number `4`.
Briefly, I wanna get the per-column count of each sorted unique value.

I have tried `np.unique(a, return_counts=True, axis=0)`, but got this wrong result:

```
(array([[2, 2, 3, 3],
        [2, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 4, 4]]),
 array([1, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: Can you try and explain your desired result more? What does 2 in `[0,0]` mean?

Comment: @jared Thanks for pointing this out. Updated.

Comment: So, given the sorted unique values, you want to know the per-column count of each?

Comment: Yes, that's the point ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use np.unique on the array to obtain the list of distinct values across the entire matrix. Then compare the unique values with the original matrix in a broadcast and sum up the matches:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,2,3,3],
              [2,3,3,3],
              [3,3,4,4]])

(np.unique(a)[:,None,None]==a).sum(axis=1)

[[2 1 0 0]
 [1 2 2 2]
 [0 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: There is no need to flatten `a` since the default functionality of `unique` is to flatten the array if `axis` is not passed.